# Unnest is not preserving nulls or empty values while inserting the data

Tags: postgresql

I have a Table Student where  I have an XML as input

```
inputXML=
<Students><student><id>1</id><Name>SAM</Name></student>
<student><id>1</id><Name>RAM</Name><Phone>123</Phone></student></Students>
```

I tried below code

```
Insert into Student (id,Name,Phone)
select * from unnest(
unnest('Students/student/id/text()',inputXML)::text[]::int[],
unnest('Students/student/Name/text()',inputXML)::text[],
unnest('Students/student/Phone/text()',inputXML)::text[]
) as T(id,Name,Phone);
```

But my table looks like

| ID | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | 123 |
| 2 | RAM | NULL |

I need my table to look like below

| ID | Name | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SAM | NULL |
| 2 | RAM | 123 |

Please suggest on preserving the data in that row
I am using postgres 14.6 for this

Comment: Additionally: your code is invalid. Are the `unnest` calls supposed to be `xpath()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The second student xml attribute has <Phone> tag

Comment: My bad I have corrected the xml It should be inside the student tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically easier done using `xmltable()`

```
select t.*
from xmltable('/Students/student' passing inputxml
               columns 
                  id int path 'id',
                  name text path 'Name',
                  phone text path 'Phone'
              ) as t
```